# Complex inequality proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $z,s\in \mathbb{C}$ ( with norm less than $1$)  then show that $\left|\frac{1-s/z}{1/z-\overline{s}}\right|<1$. I'm hoping for an algebraic proof but possibly also a proof by geometric means if possible ( even with a picture if possible).

Comment: An analytic way: Have a look at the automorphism group of the unit disk, and use the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: I don't see how to apply that theorem since $|f(0)|=|s|$ which isn't necessarily zero.

Comment: You don't apply it to this function directly, but rather *start* by recognizing this as the value of an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ evaluated at a point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\left|\frac{\alpha - \beta}{1-\bar{\alpha}\beta}\right| < 1$ when $|\alpha|,|\beta| < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-frac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1630930/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/342181/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality is equivalent to $|1 - s/z| < |1/z - \bar{s}| \iff |z - s|^2 < |1 - \bar{s} z|^2$. Expanding yields
$$ z \bar{z} + s \bar{s} - z \bar{s} - \bar{z} s < 1 - z \bar{z} s \bar{s} - z \bar{s} - s \bar{z}$$
So we need to show $|z|^2 + |s|^2 < 1 + |s|^2|z|^2$. But this is equivalent to $0 < (1 - |z|^2) ( 1 - |s|^2)$ which is clearly true since $|z|, |s| < 1$.

Comment: Seems obvious now. Thanks!